# Serverside Angular Data-tables issue

Tags: angularjs, datatables

The *https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/* link works with the rendering yet my own json file doesnt. it provides exactly the same json yet the data-table style filtering doesnt work after the data gets pulled. The link i want to use is *https://training.fuzedynasty.com/fetch.php* The link breaks the datatable styles and filtering  but with the server.herokuapp.com link code works without any issues.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Person } from '../person';


class DataTablesResponse {
  data: any[] | undefined;
  draw: number | undefined;
  recordsFiltered: number | undefined;
  recordsTotal: number | undefined;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-side-angular-way',
  templateUrl: './server-side-angular-way.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-side-angular-way.component.css']
})
export class ServerSideAngularWayComponent implements OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  persons: Person[];

  // We use this trigger because fetching the list of persons can be quite long,
  // thus we ensure the data is fetched before rendering
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {this.persons =[] }

  url = 'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/';
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        dataTablesParameters.minNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + 1;
        dataTablesParameters.maxNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + dataTablesParameters.length;
        console.log(
          dataTablesParameters.minNumber,
          dataTablesParameters.maxNumber
        );
        console.log('All Params', dataTablesParameters);
        this.httpClient
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            this.url,
            dataTablesParameters,
            {}
          )
          .subscribe((resp : any) => {
            this.persons = resp.data;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: [],
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }],
    };
  }
  }
```

```html
 <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="persons?.length != 0">
      <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
          <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody *ngIf="persons?.length == 0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Versions pre-12 have an `extractCss` property which you have to set in `angular.json`.

Comment: Hello, I'm using version 13

Comment: angular 13 /14 doesn't have that option for extractCss .. is there a another possible way to achieve **ajax call** in **angular 13** ? I'm loading over 15 000 records so an ajax call is faster than just reloading the whole table. You have to wait for +15 seconds before it loads.